# Overriding KendoUI enabled binding

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

Trying to override one of the out-of-the-box KendoUI bindings.

According to the docs, [extending](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom) by adding a new type of binding is simple enough. In fact, I have already implemented this as a fallback. But rather than forcing the whole team to go back through their code changing the `enabled` binding to `funkyEnabled` or similar, I would really like to override the existing `enabled` binding. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can try the following code

```
var BaseEnabled = kendo.data.binders.enabled;

kendo.data.binders.enabled = BaseEnabled.extend({
  init: function() {
    BaseEnabled.fn.init.apply(this, arguments);

    console.log("my enabled");
  }
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/iPEmEBa/1/edit